# How to force an application to run with Administrator rights

Tags: windows, vb6, admin, inno-setup

I'm sure this has been asked and answered before, but I can not find the answer I am looking for.  We have some old VB6 applications and am trying to run these on Windows 7.  They run fine with UAC turned 'off', but when running with the UAC at the default 'level' the applications generate (encounter) 'Requested operation requires elevation' error.  I realize that I can a) turn UAC off or b) set the program properties to 'Run this program as an administrator'; but...neither of these are desirable.  We want the PC to have normal UAC and we do NOT want that 'User Access Control: Do you want to allow the program to etc.' message box to appear every time our program starts. 
Our application is a turn-key type program, the customer turns on the PC and our application(s) start.  When I select 'Run this program as an administrator' for the application that is in the 'Startup' folder, it will NOT even start anymore (as a an auto-start application, I can still run it from explorer (and get the UAC box)).

So..Is there some way to tell Win7 to run this program as Administrator and do not ask for anything ever again.

I have tried a simple manifest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) but that really did not change anything.

I am really looking for something that can be performed from Inno setup, some sort of setting(s) that I can change that will allow our programs to read/write the Registry, start COM objects and do all the normal stuff we used to be able to do.

The issue is not running the installer 'as administrator', but running what we install 'as administrator' (without right-clicking nor 'OK'ing every time).

Comment: Wouldn't that be a massive security hole if you could circumvent the user and decided that your app runs as administrator? The whole point of that feature is that apps don't run with escalated permissions without the user's permission.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without additional code, e.g., a system service to launch your application for you.

Comment: If you attached that manifest properly, then you should see a UAC prompt appear when you start your application (assuming UAC is enabled).  As long as this is occurring, you are now at the closest you can get to your desired target without rewriting your application "properly" or requiring the user to disable UAC (which is sometimes acceptable [but not desirable] for a turn-key style app, but never for a general-purpose app).

Comment: @Miral Since we do not want (and can not) have the UAC Prompt appear and do not have the time to re-write the application(s) we are left with, as you say, disabling UAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are wanting to do is kind of counter to how UAC operates, and your requirement is effectively no different to that needed by zillions of other people when UAC became mandatory.

What you want is totally possible, but it requires that you sit back and rethink your app architecture a little. What you need to do is isolate the functionality that requires admin level access into a windows service, you then set the service to run under the `Local System` account (which arguably is slightly more privileged than a regular machine admin). Of course your service can also be set to run automatically on machine start. This means *the code in the service* gets elevated privileges without ever prompting the user.

The rest of your functionality can stay in your regular app, running under the normal user credentials.  The applications that are set to auto start are started considerably after the services, so your service should be available by the time your regular app starts.

Comment: Even this should be reserved for very special cases.  Whenever possible it is better to rework your application so that it can under a standard user token in the first place.

Comment: Seeing that it's VB6, I'm going to take a guess that to do what you describe would take somewhere around the same amount of work to just port the app to .net

Comment: @ChrisLively Yep, it's not a trivial task, the app needs to be diced up and interprocess communication needs to be worked out. I'm puzzled by your reference to porting to .Net - this wouldn't solve the issue at all. Unless you mean that all VB6 code should die die die?

Comment: @Bob77 Yes you are absolutely correct - stuff should be written so that work arounds like this are not needed. There is a lot of dodgy legacy code out there though, written back before the days of UAC and registry/filesystem virtualizing, etc.

Comment: I only brought up the .net port as during a conversion they would likely eliminate the issues that are causing the uac prompts to begin with.  Such as writing to the correct directories, replacing numerous OCX controls, etc.

Comment: @ChrisLively Ahhh okay. Replacing OCXs etc though sounds like a total rewrite rather than a straight port, so probably more work and/or risk than just splitting existing functionality between UI app and service. Personally I think a rewrite to .Net would be the better way to go.

Comment: @slugster, et.al. Thanks for all the answers. The project is being replaced.  Right, not a trivial task, few 100k LOC of VB6, dozen's of OCX's in VB6 and a dash of C++, C#, and SQL interactions.